# How to Package extension for Magento Enterprise?

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions, magento-connect, package

I need to package an extension for Magento Connect and I'm in doubt about following points:

- Do I need EE to package it ?
- Should I use a different 'Channel' ( instead of community ) ?
- Any other difference instead of packaging an ext. for CE ?

UPDATE:

**Note:**
It is advisable to upload the package for Connect 1.0

**Explanation**
Once you upload the package on Magento Connect, It will try to convert the package from 2.0 -> 1.0
This process return an error while conversion from 1.0 -> 2.0 works

**UPDATE 2**

The reason behind this question is the following:

Suppose I want to sell the extension and so my customer will download the package file from my store.

If they don't have the community channel installed:

1. the installation will fail with the following message:

> CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed. Please use
>   the MAGE shell script to install the 'community' channel.
>
> the store will go in maintenance mode
>
> the client will go in panic.
>
> Even if the above issue can be easily solved running this command: `./mage mage-setup .` ... this doesn't look like a `plug and play` solution and potentially can create damage to a store.

So the point is:

**there is any more proper way to deliver a non-free extension for EE ?**

Comment: IIRC Just bear in mind that you can't upload an extension for EE if you are not an industry partner.

Comment: Thanks @sonassi however this is not the scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is 'No', to all of your 3 questions.
The extension packer is just an UI for selecting the files of your extension and making an archive compatible with Magento Connect.
It makes no difference if the extension is for CE or EE. The version (CE/EE) will be specified when you add the extension on magento connect.

Comment: I have temporary removed the 'accepted' flag as it is not clear if you answer is complete, what about this issue:
CONNECT ERROR: The 'community' channel is not installed. Please use the MAGE shell script to install the 'community' channel.

Comment: I'm getting this issue if I install the ext. uploading the package `file` directly in the backend, looks like EE has another default channel

Comment: @Francesco I'm not sure if it's related, but I've been hearing murmurings from the community about problems with packaging extensions for connect lately: https://twitter.com/magentoconnect/status/358337868252454912

Comment: @AlanStorm Could this be related to the recent upgrade on their website (including Magento Connect)?

Comment: @Marius Every EE version, that I have used gives the same response. So I exclude it is something new.

Comment: @AlanStorm: mmm I think the issue, you are talking about it is related to my note in the question ( but maybe I'm wrong ) 
By the way it is an honor to have you here :)

Comment: @Francesco Have you initialized Magento Connect with the "./mage mage-setup" command?

Comment: @AlanStorm: sorry, I guess the question is not really clear ... I have updated the question. What you pointed out is exactly what I want to avoid as nobody wants client going in `Guru Meditation`\`Kernel Panic` :)

Comment: @Francesco It's been years since I managed an enterprise edition installation, but mage-setup was always a standard part of getting a system up and running.  Also possibly relevant to your interests: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

Comment: I guess I can trust you :) However I quite disappointed, I would preferred to be wrong and discover that the process could be address in another way ... It looks Magento guys need to put a little more effort in Magento Connect